# How to embed soname to a shared library in Qt?

Tags: qt, qml, shared-libraries

Is there a way to embed "soname" to a shared library that is created in Qt ?
Are there any flags to be assigned in .pro ?
My project.pro file contains

```
QT -= gui
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += plugin
```

I am expecting the output to be like below
For example,

```
objdump -p libxyz.so | grep SONAME
This outputs: SONAME libxyz.so
```

Comment: `LIBS += mylib` or `LIBS+=-Lmylibpath -lmylib` should work for libmylib.so, Read more [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/third-party-libraries.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the command, I have used for adding SONAME to Qt shared libraries.
Below command is added in Qt .pro file

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += patchelf --debug --set-soname libQtUILib.so libQtUILib.so
```

Below command is used to verify the SONAME

```
objdump -p libQtUILib.so | grep SONAME
  SONAME               libQtUILib.so
```